# Eclipse Import Custom Class from /src

Tags: android, eclipse

Hey I'm having a pretty basic problem importing classes into my Eclipse based Android app. I have included the class directory into the /src directory where I figured the classes would be easily included, but Eclipse is saying it "cannot resolve the classes".

One thing I noticed is that the project folder that I included and the subfolders are just regular folder and not package folder icons. Is that a problem? If so, how do I change them to packages? This is an external git repo, so I'd rather not do anything beyond just including them in my project.

Here are some pics of how I set up the project to help:

The Activity where the error is:

[image]

Here is the package structure in the project, and the package called "android-utils" where the files I'm trying to import live:

[image]

Here is how I'm importing the files:

[image]

Btw, these classes are just some utils and I'll be improving and adding to them during the development process.

Let me know if you need any in more info to help me get these files imported the right way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As your folder contains only java files Add them as Jar File in your Buildpath project, and your problem will be solved.

Also your jar file you can put it under the /libs folder
see this [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/12/create-jar-file-in-java-eclipse.html) to lean how you create jar file

Comment: add each file separately? or can i add the entire folder? Eclipse won't let me add the entire folder as a Jar... should i use "Add Jars" or "Add External Jars"? I don't have any jar files, only .class files.

Comment: Your folder contain .java files or .class files?

Comment: in the picture they are java file and you said that it contain .class files

Comment: sorry about that, yes, they contain .java files, not .class files.

Comment: see my edit, if you still have problem you can contact me on my mai see my profile

Comment: so you're suggesting that my files aren't being recognized by eclipse because i haven't turned them all into jar files? This seems pretty odd. not sure what the difference is from creating my own custom .java files outside of a project and bringing them into another project, as i could do it in any other language. seems like there is just a minor import problem. also seems tedious to turn each file into a jar, unless you could suggest a way to turn a whole package directory into a jar?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try dragging the .java files from Windows Explorer directly onto the package in Eclipse you want to put the new classes into? It should then ask to copy or link to files.

Comment: i'd rather not drag them in from external folders, it's actually a git repo that exists as a submodule in my /src folder.